# Counting length of string when only an object is passed through?

Tags: java

I'm currently on an 'Intermediate' Book for java but they don't supply the answers to most of the questions (Probably should get a new book).
but in the book they ask this question and say it's pretty easy.

*Write a class ShortWordFilter that implements the Filter interface and only accepts words that are less than 5 characters. That is the method accept will return true if the number of characters is less than 5; otherwise, the accept method returns false.*

So I implemented it on eclipse and this is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean accept(Object x) {
    return false;
}
```

I mean, I have absolutely no idea, plus I dont have a tutor to help me so I hope you guys can give me some guidance because the stuff I've tried doesn't work.

Comment: See the API for the String class. Any methods in there that might be of help? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html  And see the API for the Object class - any way to convert it to a String? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html Or cast, or (if filter is Generic) parametize the filter...

Comment: Use `toString()`. Every instance of an Object has a toString() method that will return a String representation of the Object.

Comment: `.toString().length()`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
@Override
public boolean accept(Object x) {
    if (x instanceOf String) and ((String)x).length() < 5)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I understand all of that bar the "Instance of" part.

Comment: Since x is of type Object, we use instanceOf to verify that you actually passed in a String and not some other type of object

Answer (score 2):

As a variation from nullPointer's method (even if I think its one is better) :

```
@Override
public boolean accept(Object x) {
    if (x == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return (x.toString().length() < 5);
}
```

This one accepts any object, and converts it to string. As a special case, it returns `false` for a null object.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the [Object.toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) method (dangerous if the parameter can be null)
2. [Cast the Object to a String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) (dangerous as above, and if you are not guaranteed an instance of a String as a parameter)
3. If the Filter interface is [generic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/), you can parametize it

Once the Object is a [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), you can use the length method (the API for String here is your friend).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the type of your `x` parameter has to be `Object`? Can you think of any type that represents a sequence of characters?

If your variable has to be of type`Object`, then you will need to cast it to that aforementioned type (hint: `String`) in order to treat it like a sequence of characters.

Now that you have there's a the [`length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) method if you want to find the length of a `String`.

You can then use `>` or `>=` or `<` or `<=` for comparison.

```
@Override
public boolean accept(Object x) {
    // cast x to "sequence of characters" type
    // check the length of the sequence of characters and  return appropriate true / false as appropriate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would not want to process objects that are null as well as objects that are not Strings so you can do

```
public boolean accept(Object obj) {

    if (null == obj) {
        return false;
    }
    if (! (obj instanceof String)) {
        return false;
    }

    String str = (String)obj;
    return (str.length() < 5);

}
```